# Session id is suddenly changed and user session is lost in Spring MVC application

Tags: spring-mvc, session, jsessionid

We're having problems in our web application where the session id is getting changed and the user session is lost. It happens sometimes, not always.

The timeout is random and the server assigns a new jsessionid to them.

We are loading an iFrame through our application. In the iFrame user enters the details and submits it, but when the callback comes to our web application, the session id is different. Hence the pre-existing session is not found.

We have checked the session creation time, so there is no possibility of session timeouts.